# Regular expression for email that does not allow consecutive dots before @

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm writing a regex for client form data validation through JavaScript but I can't find a way to make a regex that matches this rules:

1. Email must not begin with dot (only with number or lowercase letters),
2. Part of email before @ can have lowercase letters, numbers and dots but not consecutive ones,
3. Last character before @ must not be dot,
4. After @ there have to be at least two lowercase letters or numbers and after that there has to be at least one construction which contains dot and at least two lowercase letters.
   Emails like that should be matched by this regex:
   cary1.1grant.2@gmail.edu.us or
   1james23ste.wart@mail3.co.com
   but NOT something like this
   marilyn..monroe@gmail.co.us or .marlon12brando@yahoo.edu.us or jamescaan.@gmail.gov.fr

This is my regex but it checks end of the whole string for not allowing dot and not just before @:

```
var emailAddressModel = /^((?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9.]{6,30})[@][a-z0-9]{2,}([.][a-z]{2,})+$/;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the following ticks your boxes:

```
^[0-9a-z]+(?:\.[0-9a-z]+)*@[a-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[a-z]{2,})+$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/br2xLu/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `[0-9a-z]+` - 1+ numbers or lowercase letters.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\.[0-9a-z]+` - Literal dot followed by 1+ numbers or lowercase letters.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match 0+ times.
- `@` - Literal "@".
- `[a-z0-9]{2,}` - 2+ numbers or lowercase letters.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `\.[a-z]{2,}` - A literal dot followed by 2+ lowercase letters.
  - `)+` - Close non-capture group and match 1+ times.
- `$` - End line anchor.

If you wish to incorporate the minimum-maximum part (which is not in your requirements but in your own attempted pattern) before the "@", you could use:

```
^(?=.{6,30}@)[0-9a-z]+(?:\.[0-9a-z]+)*@[a-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[a-z]{2,})+$
```

Where the only difference is a positive lookahead to assert a position is 6-30 characters long before the "@".

Answer (score 0):

did you tried this?

`^(((?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9.]{6,30})|((?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9.]{6,29}[^.])[@][a-z0-9]{2,}([.][a-z]{2,})+)$`

1. this will exactly check if the email name between 6-30 chars
2. if there is a dot before '@' it will ignore that email